# JsonSchemaGenerator adding Minimum

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I'm trying to generate a schema using Newtonsoft JsonSchemaGenerator similar to the [following schema](http://json-schema.org/examples.html)

```
{
"title": "Example Schema",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "firstName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
        "description": "Age in years",
        "type": "integer",
        "minimum": 0
    }
},
```

}

I'm trying to create a JsonConverter and set it to the ContractResolver but I can not find a way to bind it to the specific property. 
I am tracing the code and I see the GenerateInternal on JsonSchemaGenerator (via GenerateObjectSchema) is looping through Contract.Properties and recursively calling itself but only passing property.PropertyType to itself.

```
foreach (JsonProperty property in contract.Properties)
{
. . .
    JsonSchema propertySchema = GenerateInternal(property.PropertyType, property.Required, !optional);
. . .
}


private JsonSchema GenerateInternal(Type type, Required valueRequired, bool required)
```

So if I have a class with 2 integer properties with different ranges it won't be able to create different schemas for each.

Comment: json.net uses draft 3. You can not use "required" as an array, which is draft 4.

Comment: Hi Jruizaranguren, I removed the "required" as it was not my problem. Thanks

Comment: Well, If you plan to use json.net for working with json schema you will end up with problems (because it is draft 3 and not a strategic feature in the library)